# How do I add an ACF shortcode to a non-ACF page?

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I'm going round in circles with this one, so need some help please.

I've setup a basic ACF group for Event type page using Date, Location, a link and description.  I have these fields located to any post type that is equal to Event.  This works fine, I can click add new event and see the fields etc. When I add these they get added under /events/new event/ which is what I want.

Where I am stuck is that I want to create a kind of list page with all the events, where you can see all events and click through to each one.

I am using a theme built off twentytwentythree with some custom gutenberg builder blocks using generateblocks and astra.  Generateblocks has a queryloop block that I can use to loop through event posts but that only shows the post title and none of the ACF specific info for each event.  I have tried to add the acf shortcode in and loop through that but it doesn't show anything.  I guess the ACF fields are exposed at this point?

Can someone point me in the right direction of how to create this list style page please?

Thanks

Comment: It appears the ID of the current post is not accessible via native WordPress functions in the query loop block. You will need to create a custom block to access the ID https://generatepress.com/forums/topic/gb-query-loop-display-acf-datas-via-shortcode/